# how to echo/print a nicely formatted array to the modx log?

Tags: php, modx

I'm trying to figure out how to print/echo a formatted array to the modx error log. but print_r & pre tags do not work, if I use something like:

```
$log = "<pre>";
$log .= print_r($formdata);
$log .= "</pre>";
$this->modx->log(modX::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, 'Form Data = ' . $log);
```

the result in the log is:

```
[2014-12-20 22:35:18] (ERROR @ /index.php) Form Data = <pre>1</pre>
```

I have seen formatted arrays in the modx logs before, does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in [**`print_r()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) function add 2<sup>nd</sup> argument `TRUE` for return output value, see below sample code

```
$log = "<pre>";
$log .= print_r($formdata, true);
$log .= "</pre>";
$this->modx->log(modX::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, 'Form Data = ' . $log);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `"<pre>" - "</pre>"` tags, just

`$modx->log(xPDO::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, "Form Data = " . print_r($formdata,true),'','mySnippet');`

will do the job, as of Revo version 2.3.3 at any rate.